# PHP Retrieve mysql stored character data based on selected option within <selection> returns wrong character

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Ok I'm confused. See code below.

1. It loads all characters properly into the  list.
2. I never receive any errors.

However, something isn't really working. Because it doesn't matter what character I select and press select character, it always retrieve the character by the name "SUPERADMIN" in the database. I thought it could be a session screwing up but I'm not logged in on the account which has the character SUPERADMIN. Any ideas where I screwed up? :S

```
        <!-- START: Load all characters from database, and put them in dropdown -->                                    
<form method="post" action="admin_settings.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="slct_id">                               
        <select name="names">
            <option value = "">---Select---</option>
<?php
    $stmt = $mysqli_0001->prepare("SELECT role_name FROM mugame_0001.mu_role");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($slct_name);
    while ($stmt->fetch()){
        echo "<option value='$slct_name'>$slct_name</option>";
    }
    $stmt->close();
?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="indoc_dochrselect" value="Select Character">
 </form>
        <!-- END: Load all characters from database, and put them in dropdown -->

        <div class="nk-gap-2"></div> <!-- Creates a neat gap between the two thingie-mackdodies $ -->

                <!-- START: Load character information based on the selected character -->  
                <?PHP
                if (isset($_POST['indoc_dochrselect'])) {
                    $slct_id = $slct_name;
                    //$id = $_POST['id'];
                    if  ($stmt = $mysqli_web->prepare("SELECT * from mugame_0001.mu_role WHERE role_name = ?")) {
                    $stmt->bind_param("s", $slct_id);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $res = $stmt->get_result();
                    $data = $res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            foreach ($data as $row) 
        {
            echo "<form action='php/mysqli_action_admin.php' method='post'>";
            echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='char_name' placeholder='" . $row['role_name'] . "'>";
            echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='char_level' placeholder='" . $row['role_level'] . "'>";
            echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='char_money' placeholder='" . $row['money'] . "'>";
            echo "<button class='nk-btn link-effect-4 float-right' name='do_adm_getinfo_selected_role_update'>Update Character</button>";
            echo "</form>";
                        }
                    }   
                }
?>
                <!-- END: Load character information based on the selected character -->
```

Comment: Just a tip (not a solution): `echo "<option value='$slct_name'>$slct_name</option>";` is more simply written as `echo "<option>$slct_name</option>";` with the same effect.

Comment: I didn't know that, I'll edit the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bound_result variable `$slct_name` is flowing downscript.

This seems to be the culprit: `$slct_id = $slct_name;`

You are using the final fetched value, but I believe you want to use the POSTed value.

I am assuming that the final fetched value is `SUPERADMIN`.

I believe you want to use `$_POST['names']` as that is the name attribute in your select field.

Comment: Worked! Thank you a lot. I'll mark your comment as the answer as soon as stackoverflow lets me! :) Cheers.